# Falha ao efetuar push

Tags: git

Ao efetuar o push em minha maquina recebi o seguinte erro :

> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another
>   repository pushing hint: to the same ref. You may want to first
>   integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before
>   pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push
>   --help' for details.

Por que está acontecendo isso e como resolver ?

Comment: Parece que esse repositório que você está tentado subir suas coisas possui alterações que não está no seu commit. Tenta fazer o que está pedindo, um git pull... para buscar as "coisas" que estão lá no repositórios antes de tentar fazer push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No remoto há mudanças que você ainda não tem como consideradas na sua versão local. Deve fazer um git pull e resolver os conflitos de merge antes, caso existam, e só depois fazer o git push.